# Tamanho ocupado em disco por uma tabela no SQLite

Tags: android, sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite, sqlite3

No Oracle, quando desejamos saber o quanto uma tabela ocupa de disco podemos fazer uma consulta ao dicionário `dba_segments`.

```
SELECT segment_name, segment_type, bytes/1024/1024 MB
FROM dba_segments
WHERE segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='<nome-tabela>';
```

No banco SQLite como saber o quanto uma tabela está ocupando exatamente no disco? Existe um dicionário? Já vi péssimas soluções de cálculo matricial para devolver o dado que eu não gostaria de usar que dá um cálculo furado por razões óbvias (superestimado):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) *  -- The number of rows in the table
     ( 24 +        -- The length of all 4 byte int columns
       12 +        -- The length of all 8 byte int columns
       128 )       -- The estimate of the average length of all string columns
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você precisa saber o tamanho exato durante a execução do seu código, está lascado. A única forma que vejo é ler a tabela toda e ir somando os tamanhos reais ocupados. E isso nem dá pra fazer de forma direta. Tem que ver a implementação interna para calcular o tamanho de algumas colunas. E se a implementação mudar, já era. Ou seja, nem perca tempo com isto.

Se só precisa ter uma ideia em algum momento por organização sua, é possível usar o [`sqlite_anlyzer`](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Talvez possa ler a saída via código, mas é gambiarra. De qualquer forma não tem pronto pra Android. Teria que compilar, talvez até adaptar para rodar nele.

Se for muito importante saber sempre o tamanho da tabela (duvido) é possível fazer outra gambiarra. Criei um `TRIGGER` que vá mantendo um acumulador em cada escrita feita na tabela. Este acumulador terá sempre o tamanho da tabela. Não é tão simples fazer, tem *overhead* e cria um fardo pra manutenção (ainda que possa abstrair isto), mas é uma solução (...questionável). Basicamente o que o Oracle faz :)

Já vi outras "soluções", uma pior que a outra.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: fato! Eu queria trabalhar com um cálculo para cache de uma solução específica, mas mudei a forma de pensar na arquitetura ;-) Mutíssimo obrigado pela colaboração!